How to eliminate voltage spike when power supply is switched on with mechanical switches
Let me set the scene first: we have a special racing vehicle, where the power souce is a 12s Lipo battery pack (Nominal Voltage = 48V, Maximum = 52V). The battery is protected by our own Battery Management System (BMS). The BMS is responsible for turning on/off the main relay, which powers the whole system. We also have to use two emergency switches, which turn on or turn off the BMS itself. I have included a very basic schematic about the system: (Picture 1) 
Now to the problem: when we turn on the emergency switches, the BMS gets the power to operate. However sometimes we had a BMS failure, which means the PCB itself is short circuited. We have taken a look at the switching line (between the Power switches and the BMS positive terminal), and these are the results: (Picture 2) 
Now as can be seen on the picture, we have a voltage spike, up to 64V, sometimes lower, sometimes higher. The spike itself lasts about 2-3ns. Now why is that a problem? The BMS has a DCDC converter which can tolerate input voltages up to 55V. We suspect that these voltage spikes on turn ons are the reason we get short circuits, because the converter cant tolerate them.
Here is the schematics for the BMS DCDC converter: (Picture 3)

I would like to ask for your help, how we could eliminate these spikes, because whe have a limited number of BMSs left, and its really frustrating to repair them.
EDIT: for some reason I cant upload more images, I ll try in the comments. Images are uploaded here with the respective names.

Put the links to the pictures under the comments, we'll try to add them into the question body.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qI3Pt92ymc_7NrvxrbbR3vbBbfVCmm0E?usp=sharing
I have uploaded them here, thanks!

I couldn't upload them either. Actually, I can't upload any images to anywhere on EE.SE. There must be a server problem.

Quick answer from me: put a ferrite bead in line, followed by a good sized cap. Size and ratings of both devices depend on your circuit and use.

Maybe use flyback diodes across relays, and add decoupling capacitors and TVS diodes to shunt and suppress voltage spikes?


The wiring inductance and the DC-DC's input caps form a resonant LC circuit which is excited by the voltage pulse from the switch closing. This LC circuit creates a voltage spike that fries your chip. This is a common problem in devices powered with wall warts because the wiring to the wall wart is long, the wall wart is a SMPS so it has low ESR output caps, and there is usually a ferrite bead followed by low-ESR ceramic caps on the device input.
The solution is to add damping to the LC circuit so it no longer resonates but instead settles to the input voltage without overshooting. Basically you need the damping factor to be high:
\$ \zeta = \frac{R}{2}\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}} > 1 \$
If L is your wiring or PCB inductance it is hard to reduce it. You can increase R by putting a resistor in series, but that causes losses.
So a simple solution is to add a capacitor on the input of the DC-DC. This should be a general purpose "high-ESR" model, with much higher capacitance than the actual decoupling caps, so it dominates the transient response and provides damping by increasing both C and R. In this case the cap is used as a snubber, with the snubber's resistor being the ESR. It's also possible to use a RC snubber with two discrete components.
Finding the correct values depends on wiring inductances so it's not necessarily obvious, but it'll probably be in the "a few hundreds of µF, a few ohms" range.
Another solution is to put an inductor and a resistor in parallel on the input. This also makes a filter at the input of the DC-DC which can be useful, and it reduces turn-on current surge, unlike the capacitor solution which increases it.
If you desolder the shorted chip from your dead BMS, you can use it to experiment with various component values.
Note that the 10µF+100nF is likely not enough decoupling for the input of a 1.2A buck DC-DC, unless maybe the 10µF has very low ESR and inductance.
Some examples: red had a lot of overshoot, the other two options are well damped.


Thanks! We have increased the input capacitance, it seems that will do it!

We miss pictures and so on, but you can probably get a long way by thinking about the electrical reason for your problem, which is this : the spike happens when a large change of current occurs through some inductance.
So start by looking for sources of inductance. Relay coils need protection diodes across them to prevent voltage spikes, this has killed many driver circuits. Other than that, stray inductance in wiring can be a problem. Minimise the length of cables that switch large currents, and try to run them in as direct a path as possible.
The other possibility is to reduce the rate of change of current, by adding a small amount of series resistance - however this can be tricky as it will cause the supply voltage to vary slightly if load current changes. It is common to add large reservoir capacitors after the resistance which can reduce this problem (and also helps reduce the spikes). There are also active devices which can limit surge current
There are also surge protection devices, essentially zener diodes, but it is always better to remove or reduce the problem when possible.
How you apply these ideas depends a lot on your load current and physical design of your project but the key is to reduce inductance and slow down the rate of change of current.
NOTE - if you are seeing a spike of 64V with a scope, the real peak value could be a lot larger, but the act of connecting the scope might be reducing the amplitude.
